# Recursive parent/child relationships in Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am having a problem updating relationships in my Ember app:  I have a `node` object that has  the following model definition:

```
App.Node = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
    children: DS.hasMany('node', {
        inverse: 'parent',
        async: true
    }),
    parent: DS.belongsTo('node', {
        inverse: 'children',
        async: true
    })
});
```

Then I am doing this in my 'new' controller.

```
add: function() {
    var model = this.get('newModel'),
        rec,
        self = this,
        parent = this.get('model');

    rec = this.store.createRecord('node', model);
    rec.set('parent', parent);
    rec.save().then(function(newrec) {
        parent.get('children').addObject(newrec);
        parent.save().then(function(resolve) {
            self.transitionToRoute('node');
        }, function(reject) {
            console.log("ERR UPDATE PARENT:", reject);
        });
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(
            'Unable to add node "%@": %@.'.fmt(name, err.statusText));
    });
}
```

What happens is that the child node is saved (with a POST) correctly.  The `parent` property has the ID of the parent node.  Then I try to add the newly created child to the parent and save the parent.  This works (with a PUT) but the 'children' property is missing altogether from the payload to the server.  What am I doing wrong??